# cmake error for header-only library: `include could not find load file`

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been trying to change a makefile c++ project into a cmake project, and I've been having som difficulty. `cmake` seems to be looking for stuff in `/usr/local/lib/` instead of `/usr/local/include/` and I'm not sure why that is.

This library is header-only, and so I've been following [this tutorial](https://dominikberner.ch/cmake-interface-lib/) My header-only library in `include` seems to "build" fine, but I keep getting the following error when I try to generate a makefile to build my example program:

```
me:~/pf/examples/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/pf/pfConfig.cmake:27 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/pf/pf_exampleTargets.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)
```

`examples/CMakeLists.txt` creates another fresh project:

```
project(pf_example)

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# "install" pf
find_package(pf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

file(GLOB SOURCES ${PROJECT_NAME}/*.{h,cpp})
message("${SOURCES}")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pf::pf)
```

The root directory `CMakeLists.txt` file is more complicated. It's the one that was adapted from the tutorial I mentioned above:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project("pf" VERSION 1.0.1
             DESCRIPTION "A header only c++ template library for fast particle filtering."
             HOMEPAGE_URL "https://github.com/tbrown122387/pf")

include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
            $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE cxx_std_17)


install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Targets
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file("${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
                                 VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
                                 COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)


configure_package_config_file(
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION
  ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake)

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Targets
        FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake
        NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake)


install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
              "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake)

install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include DESTINATION include)
```

To install this header only library, before I try to build the examples project, I typed the following commands into the command line:

```
cd ~/pf
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local/include
sudo cmake --build . --config Release --target install -- -j $(nproc)
```

I didn't post it, but there's also a file `cmake/pfconfig.cmake.in` that is verbatim copied from the tutorial above.

Comment: `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local/include` No. `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local/`. Why would you put cmake stuff into `CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR`?

Comment: According to the `install(EXPORT)` command, you have `pf_Targets.cmake` file which describes the targets (`PROJECT_NAME` is `pf` in your case). Why do you include `pf_exampleTargets.cmake` file in your `pfconfig.cmake`?

Comment: Which line are you referring to @Tsyvarev ?

Comment: I refer to the error message, which is about inclusion of the file `/usr/local/lib/cmake/pf/pf_exampleTargets.cmake`. Your main project doesn't contain the word `example`, how it is appeared in the config file...

Comment: @Tsyvarev no idea. perhaps they are cached there from an earlier attempt with different files

Comment: As far as I understand, these are files remaining from your previous attempts. Your new files are installed under `/usr/local/include` prefix, which is not't checked by CMake automatically. Well, you could set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to contain that prefix (and remove old files). But as noted by KamilCuk, it is better to not use `/usr/local/include` **prefix** at all: `/usr/local/include` is a standard **include directory** and adding unrelated files here would just pollute your system. You may use `/usr/local` as an installation prefix: here CMake searches files by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your install prefix is specified as `/usr/local/include` so the files would be installed as:

- headers into `/usr/local/include/include`
- libraries into `/usr/local/include/libs`
- cmake stuff into `/usr/local/include/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake`

Those paths are just wrong. Just set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local` (ie. remove `include)` and install it inside `/usr/local/` tree.

Answer (score 0):

A few took care of this issue.

1. in `CMakeLists.txt` change `install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include DESTINATION include)` to `install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/pf DESTINATION include)` so the files don't clutter up the installation locations. This also requires creating `pf/include/pf` and moving all the files in `pf/include` to `pf/include/pf`.
2. Follow advice in [@KamilCuk's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62867194/1267833) answer.
3. In `examples/CMakeLists.txt` change `file(GLOB SOURCES ${PROJECT_NAME}/*.{h,cpp})` to `file(GLOB SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)`

Also note that my `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` were quite cluttered up due to my numerous earlier failed attempts, so I deleted a bunch of files in there and re-installed fresh.

Comment: Your project already uses [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) module, which provides installation paths for many of common needs. With that module you rarely need *hand-written* directories in `DESTINATION` clause for the `install()` command. E.g. a variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR` provided by the module is intended to be used for the headers files.